# Constructing an L2 function from an entire function bounded on R

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have an entire function $f(z)$ of exponential type $\tau\geq0$ that is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ and zero at every member of the complex sequence $\{\lambda_n\}$. What I want is an entire function of exponential type at most $\tau$ that is zero on $\{\lambda_n\}$ and square integrable over $\mathbb{R}$. (I want this so I can use the Paley-Wiener Theorem). Does the existence of the latter follow from the existence of the former?

The exponential type of a function $f(z)$ is the smallest nonnegative number $\tau$ such that $$\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|\leq e^{(\tau+\epsilon)r}$$ for all $\epsilon>0$ for sufficiently large $r$.

Of course, I can multiply $f(z)$ by something like $e^{-z^2}$, but the result is no longer of exponential type on $\mathbb{C}$.

Again, this is related to an exercise from Robert Young I'm trying to do.

Comment: Actually, I think I may have solved this. If we let $g(z)=\int_{-A}^{A}e^{izt}\,dt$, then I think $g$ is entire, of exponential type at most $\epsilon$, and square integrable on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $g(z)f(z)$ will be the function I'm looking for. It's of exponential type no more than $\tau+\epsilon$, but I can take a limit as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$.

Comment: I think taking $\epsilon\to 0$ will be problematic here: the sequence will converge locally uniformly, but may lose the square integrability.

Comment: I think the function $\sin \tau x$ gives you a counterexample; namely, there is no (of course, non-zero) entire function of the same exponential type and with the same zeros, which is square-summable on the real line.